# Add Class to dictionary

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

ItemsByGuid definition:

```
private Dictionary<string, Channel> ItemsByGuid = new Dictionary<string, Channel>();
```

i have a class:

```
public class Channel
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and i try to add the class to a dictionary:

```
Channel _Channel = Utils.LoadXML<Channel>(file)
ItemsByGuid.Add(_Channel.Guid, _Channel);
```

im getting the error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Add(string, MyCMSDreams.Content.Channels.Channel)' has some invalid arguments
"
any idea why?

Comment: What does Utils.LoadXML return? What's the rest of the error message?

Comment: Show your definition for ItemsByGuid.

Comment: _Channel.Guid should _Channel.Guid.ToString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that you're passing a `Guid` and `Channel` objects into your `Add()` method, your ItemsByGuid defition should look something like this:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Channel> ItemsByGuid = new Dictionary<Guid, Channel>();
```

Does it?

Comment: Ahh, the string - there's the issue.  :)